# Docker for Windows: is it possible to install a printer?

Tags: docker, printing, nano-server, server-core

I have a .NET application which generates some reports in PDF format and sends them to a printer.
The printer is a network printer which is available directly via IP (no print server).

Right now this application is hosted on a Windows Server-based machine which has this printer installed.

Is it possible to pack this application in a Docker container? Which base image should I use? How to install a network printer with the corresponding drivers in a Docker container?

Comment: Hi have you had any progress with this? I print via USB and would like to do it in Win-based docker. Do you know how to approach this?

Comment: I ended up creating a separate Linux-based container with CUPS (print server) and sending the documents there using IPP (Internet Printing Protocol, HTTP-based).

Comment: Hi, byt you were able to install the drivers on linux right? I have a problem of being limited to Windows since Epson does not provide drivera for unix systems for that printer :(

Comment: Yes, there are drivers for almost all popular printers. I used HP.

Comment: I will give it a go over the weekend, but there wasnt a driver for my printer in CUPS and neither could I use the printer at all on any Linux distro